# How to make a large variable global in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a simple web application that utilizes a moderately large NLP model, which is the same for all users and ideally I hope to re-load the model from a new model file generated daily.

Is there a way to make the variable storing this model to be global? Loading it from a file every time a user uses it would be quite slow and it seems to be too large (~1GB) to be put into sessions.

Thank you!

Comment: You are correct.  It is too big to load.  You probably don't want a 1 GB variable hanging around your code.  Maybe rethink how the user interacts with the model?  When you use Google translate, it doesn't load the translation engine into your web page.  You submit the phrase you want to translate the phrase flies off somewhere and it returns with a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a top-level variable inside a module, and then other code can just `import` it.

If it needs to be refreshed every day, wrap it in an accessor function:

```
# data_manager.py

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
data = None
last_load_time = None

def get_data():
    global data
    global last_load_time
    if last_load_time is None or last_load_time + timedelta(hours=24) < datetime.now():
        data = some_expensive_function()
        last_load_time = datetime.now()
    return data
```

Then other modules can just call `get_data()`.  The data will remain loaded in the module as long as some other module has it imported; generally this would be the lifespan of your webserver worker processes.